# Classic ASP (Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")) returning no data in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-7

I have migrated a a classic ASP files from IIS 6 to IIS 7.5

After migrating, the line `Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")` doesn't return any value, because of which the application is not running.

The Anonymous Authentication is already disabled in IIS. Is there any other setting i need to check. Please someone help me on this.

Comment: Is Basic or Windows authentication enabled?

Comment: Windows Authentication is Enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have also allowed anonymous access?

Excerpt from here ([Microsoft KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306359)), highlight by me:

This problem occurs because the authentication-related variables in the ServerVariables collection are not populated if you use Anonymous Access security to access the .aspx page. *This problem can also occur if you give the Anonymous user access in the  section of the Web.config file*.

Comment: Hi, there is no Web.Config file as its very old classic asp project. 
And IIS manager i have made Anonymous Authentication disabled and enabled just the Windows authentidation.

Comment: But you can add a web.config file also for classic ASP projects, since these are for IIS configuration. We are using them for defining URL rewriting rules for our classic ASP pages.